# How to convert a web site optimized for mobile into a downloadable mobile app for Android?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a web site that is powered by ColdFusion, SQL Server, and jQuery. I built a version of the main site and optimized it for mobile using jQuery Mobile. It works exactly how I want it to work.  (You can view the site here: ( http://www.flyingpiston.com/mobile/ )

I have been asked to convert this site into an application that can be downloaded from the main site. I see no advantage to doing so, but I need to get it done.  My client wants a visitor to be able to install the site on their phone so that it appears to be a full-fledged web app that starts by clicking on an icon on the mobile device, not like a web site in a browser.

The site needs to pull fresh content from a database along with fresh images that are hosted on the main web site. So, this is not a static site.

It has been suggested that I run my code through Phone Gap and it will output an Android application for me. This sounds too simple.

Where do I start in making this mobile optimized site into a downloadable application?

Comment: The phonegap tutorials are pretty easy to follow.  I haven't done it with a CF site before, but in my experience, it's really just as easy as putting the script/html/css files together in a zipped folder and uploading it to PG's build server.  Although if  the only thing the client wants is something they can pull down as an .apk and one-tap launch from their android desktop (no native app functionality), you could just create a dummy html page that's literally nothing more than a redirect to your actual site and package the zip with an icon.  Just run it through PG build and you're done.

Comment: Wow! You might have just given me what I need. To be clear, I can make an downloadable web app that consists solely of an stylish html page that redirects to a web site on the click of a logo, or something really simple.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get away with not having to rebuild the whole site you can always use a WebView and load the site that way. I just did this for a client with great success. You can even use the WebView to interact with Android directly so you can have access to GPS, camera, sensors, etc. I even added an action bar and the navigation drawer to give it a full feel of a native app. You avoid having to create it twice and all updates to the mobile site are automatically updated on the app. You should note that if there are links to external sites or to other apps on the phone (like maps or the phone app) you'll have to override the default URL action and load it properly outside of your WebView which is done using the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. The benefit is that you have a native app that can leverage all the functionality of Android should it be necessary.

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Interesting! I will be checking it out today.

Comment: I can actually send you sample code that I'm using. I spent a ton of time on this and don't really have a problem sharing my results. There is so much nuance involved and I can save you a lot of trouble. I don't know how I could share that much code though.